# Will a UWP app built for x86 run on x64?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm having a problem, and found a suggestion to build for x86 only. But I'm not sure, though x86 can run on x64 computers, does that mean it will run as a UWP app as well, and be offered to x64 clients?

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh454036(v=vs.140)) weren't clear.

Comment: Also consider arm with x86 and x64 so you can reach to every device i.e mobile(arm),tablet(arm or x64,x86),pc, hololense,etc.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** An x86 only UWP app will run on Windows x64 consumer systems, but won't run on Xbox One or older Windows ARM-based devices.

Generally speaking modern Windows x64 desktop PCs have the "Windows-on-Windows" layer which supports running 32-bit applications as well as 64-bit native apps for improved compatibility. That said, there are 64-bit versions of Windows that do not support running 32-bit apps like Windows Server (it's an optional feature) or Xbox One (which can only run x64 native apps). In these cases, a UWP package with only x86 would not run.

x86 and ARM has to date mostly been relevant to Windows Mobile platforms. There are some recently released [Windows 10 on ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/apps-on-arm) devices entering the market that can run x86 or ARM, but not x64 applications.

x64 works on most Windows desktop PCs and Xbox One. Depending on the exact market segment you are targeting and your application type, you could go with just an x64 only architecture package--this is mostly relevant to high-end games or heavy performance applications.

> Ideally you would ship your UWP app for all supported architectures including x86, x64 native, and ARM assuming you are able to actually test them all.

See [Windows 64](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/12/16/windows-x64/), [UWP on Xbox One](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/), and [DirectX and UWP on Xbox One](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2017/12/15/directx-and-uwp-on-xbox-one/)

Comment: The best way to maximize your addressable market is to submit all possible packages (currently x86, x64, and ARM32)

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Until MS has a bug that _might_ be only on x64 and so might fixed by running x86 only. As for ARM - is that any more alive than Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Do you have an answer to my original question (this answer doesn't really address that)?

Comment: There are ARM Windows PCs; it's not limited to just phones. Yes an x86 UWP that runs on an x64 CPU is still running as a UWP, but as @Chuck says not all x64 systems support x86 apps.

Comment: @ispiro What aspect of your original question is not answered here? I updated the answer somewhat to be clearer. I don't understand the comment "Until MS has a bug that might be only on x64 and so might fixed by running x86 only". Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: My question was  `...and be offered to x64 clients`. I know the x86 build can run on x64. I built it for x86 and it runs on my x64. But that doesn't mean that someone on an x64 browsing the MS Store will see or be allowed (by the Store app) to install it on their x64.

Comment: @ispiro This sounds like a standard C# problem. If your C# program is loading a DLL, it has to be supported for both x86 and x64 native if you build with ``/platform:anycpu``. If you only have x86 versions of the DLLs you use, then you must use ``/platform:x86``.

Comment: Perhaps you are hitting [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5456). What do you have set as your Target version and your Minimum version of Windows 10? What builds of Windows 10 are the testers hitting the issue running?

Comment: The issue was eventually solved by help here on SO (by some `MSFT` user) so I removed my comments regarding that, leaving my original question only. Thanks for the information. BTW Without @ispiro I don't get notified of your replies.

Answer (score 1):

an x86 build will NOT run on
1) windows rt/Windows S
2) xbox.
3) any windows mobile variant.

it will run on
1) windows for desktop either natively or under the WOW architecture. both 32 and 64 bit versions.
2) windows 10 for ARM 64 bit os (via win32 emulation layer under WOW.) any device that has this OS will work.
3) Hololens (requires x86)
4) IOT Core, depending on your device.
5) Surface Hub (whatever that is)

By now you can also compile arm64, which only runs on windows 10 for ARM.